# How can I change what's displayed at a login shell?

Tags: bash, login, prompt, profile

I'm getting more familiar with tweaking the way things look in a shell via the prompt (`.bashrc`), but I'm now trying to change the initial stuff displayed when I first log in. On my EC2 instance, this is what I see when I log in:

```
         __|  __|_  )  Fedora 8
         _|  (     /    32-bit
        ___|\___|___|


  Welcome to: 

    Wowza Media Server 2 for Amazon EC2

      Version: 2.0.0.08
```

On my home Mint computer, here's what I see when I log in:

```
Welcome to Linux Mint 11 Katya (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64)

Welcome to Linux Mint
* Documentation:  http://www.linuxmint.com

Last login: Tue Jun 21 17:44:05 2011
```

Where is this defined? How can I tweak it for some mad ASCII art **ACTION**?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The text displayed before the login prompt is stored in `/etc/issue` (there's a related file, `/etc/motd`, that's displayed after the user logs in, before their shell is started). It's just a normal text file, but it accepts a bunch of escape sequences:

- **`\b`** -- Baudrate of the current line.
- **`\d`** -- Current date.
- **`\s`** -- System name, the name of the operating system.
- **`\l`** -- Name of the current tty line.
- **`\m`** -- Architecture identifier of the machine, eg. i486
- **`\n`** -- Nodename of the machine, also known as the hostname.
- **`\o`** -- Domainname of the machine.
- **`\r`** -- Release number of the OS, eg. 1.1.9.
- **`\t`** -- Current time.
- **`\u`** -- Number of current users logged in.
- **`\U`** -- The string "1 user" or " users" where is the number of current users logged in.
- **`\v`** -- Version of the OS, eg. the build-date etc.

---

On my machine I have:

> This is \n (\s \m \r) \t \l

Which is rendered as:

> This is etudes-1 (Linux x86_64 2.6.39-gentoo) 17:43:10 tty1

Answer (score 19):

The OP clearly is asking about messages displayed AFTER log in, all "/etc/issue" are displayed BEFORE login+password is entered so are off-topic.

The 'login shell' steps are:

1. show messages contained in `/etc/issue`
2. ask for user and password
3. show *Message Of The Day* from:

   `/etc/motd`

   `/etc/update-motd.d`
4. start `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`

NB .bashrc is executed for NON-login shell

@Naftuli Kay add your ASCII art to `/etc/motd` you can also put a script in `/etc/update-motd.d`; for user independent prints the script can go in `/etc/profile`. `~/.bash_profile` for single user prints

Comment: I want to know how to change the login prompt.(where the user is asked to enter username)

Comment: @Ayush login is responsible for the step 2, the login prompt. It is not much configurable, see `$ man login` for all the (few) available options

Answer (score 7):

The file `/etc/issue` and `/etc/issue.net` are the files displayed by the login program. You can put special expansion characters in it, as noted on the other answer. But you may also want to try the [linux_logo](http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/linux_logo/) program. It can generate really nice ASCII art issue files for you.

Answer (score 4):

From [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-gnome-terminal-splash-screen/1020693#1020693):

[image: Ubuntu splash screen.png]

Check the **Ask Ubuntu** link above for comments and possibly new answers from other users.

## `now` bash script

The heavy lifting is the splash component that shows this:

```
$ now

Weather report: Edmonton               March 2018            ┌────────────────────────────┐
                                  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa       │   ┏━┓╺┓  ┏━┓┏━┓   ┏━┓┏┳┓   │
     \   /     Sunny                           1  2  3       │   ┃┃┃ ┃ ╹┏━┛┗━┫   ┣━┛┃┃┃   │
      .-.      -23--14 °C          4  5  6  7  8  9 10       │   ┗━┛╺┻╸╹┗━╸┗━┛   ╹  ╹ ╹   │
   ― (   ) ―   ↘ 22 km/h          11 12 13 14 15 16 17       └────────────────────────────┘
      `-’      14 km              18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
     /   \     0.9 mm             25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Yes it really is -14 in Edmonton and feels like -23. A good time to spend the long-weekend inside playing the newly arrived Tomb Raider 2013! Maybe brush up on that Resume to move to Vancouver or Montreal...

Here is the code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: now
# PATH: $HOME/bin
# DESC: Display current weather, calendar and time
# CALL: Called from terminal or ~/.bashrc
# DATE: Apr 6, 2017. Modified: Mar 30, 2018.

# NOTE: To display all available toilet fonts use this one-liner:
#       for i in ${TOILET_FONT_PATH:=/usr/share/figlet}/*.{t,f}lf; do j=${i##*/}; toilet -d "${i%/*}" -f "$j" "${j%.*}"; done

# Setup for 92 character wide terminal
DateColumn=34 # Default is 27 for 80 character line, 34 for 92 character line
TimeColumn=61 # Default is 49 for   "   "   "   "    61 "   "   "   "

#--------- WEATHER ----------------------------------------------------------

# Current weather, already in color so no need to override
echo " "
# Replace Edmonton with your city name, GPS, etc. See: curl wttr.in/:help
curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0 --silent --max-time 3
# Timeout #. Increase for slow connection---^

echo " "
echo " "                # Pad with blank lines for calendar & time to fit

#--------- DATE -------------------------------------------------------------

# calendar current month with today highlighted.
# colors 00=bright white, 31=red, 32=green, 33=yellow, 34=blue, 35=purple,
#        36=cyan, 37=white

tput sc                 # Save cursor position.
# Move up 9 lines
while [ $((++i)) -lt 10 ]; do tput cuu1; done

# Depending on length of your city name and country name you will:
#   1. Comment out next three lines of code. Uncomment fourth code line.
#   2. Change subtraction value and set number of print spaces to match
#      subtraction value. Then place comment on fourth code line.

Column=$(($DateColumn - 10))
tput cuf $Column        # Move x column number
printf "          "     # Blank out ", country" with x spaces
#tput cuf $DateColumn    # Position to column 27 for date display


# -h needed to turn off formating: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013954/bash-substring-stringoffsetlength-error/1013960#1013960
cal -h > /tmp/terminal

CalLineCnt=1
Today=$(date +"%d")
# Prefix with space when length < 2
if [[ ${#Today} < 2 ]] ; then
    Today=" "$Today
fi
printf "\033[32m"   # color green -- see list above.

while IFS= read -r Cal; do
    printf "$Cal"
    if [[ $CalLineCnt > 2 ]] ; then
        # See if today is on current line & invert background
        tput cub 22
        for (( j=0 ; j <= 18 ; j += 3 )) ; do
            Test=${Cal:$j:2}            # Current day on calendar line
            if [[ "$Test" == "$Today" ]] ; then
                printf "\033[7m"        # Reverse: [ 7 m
                printf "$Today"
                printf "\033[0m"        # Normal: [ 0 m
                printf "\033[32m"       # color green -- see list above.
                tput cuf 1
            else
                tput cuf 3
            fi
        done
    fi

    tput cud1               # Down one line
    tput cuf $DateColumn    # Move 27 columns right
    CalLineCnt=$((++CalLineCnt))
done < /tmp/terminal

printf "\033[00m"           # color -- bright white (default)
echo ""

tput rc                     # Restore saved cursor position.

#-------- TIME --------------------------------------------------------------

tput sc                 # Save cursor position.
# Move up 9 lines
i=0
while [ $((++i)) -lt 10 ]; do tput cuu1; done
tput cuf $TimeColumn    # Move 49 columns right

# Do we have the toilet package?
if hash toilet 2>/dev/null; then
    echo " "$(date +"%I:%M %P")" " | \
        toilet -f future --filter border > /tmp/terminal
# Do we have the figlet package?
elif hash figlet 2>/dev/null; then
    echo $(date +"%I:%M %P") | figlet > /tmp/terminal
# else use standard font
else
    echo $(date +"%I:%M %P") > /tmp/terminal
fi

while IFS= read -r Time; do
    printf "\033[01;36m"    # color cyan
    printf "$Time"
    tput cud1               # Up one line
    tput cuf $TimeColumn    # Move 49 columns right
done < /tmp/terminal

tput rc                     # Restore saved cursor position.

exit 0
```

### Prerequisites

For the fancy time display you need to install `toilet`:

```bash
sudo apt install toilet
```

For another fancy time display (but not quite as fancy) install `figlet`:

```bash
sudo apt install figlet
```

Otherwise the time will be displayed in "normal" font.

### Weather

Weather is provided by the `curl wttr.in/cityname?0` command. In your terminal use: `curl wttr.in/:help` for additional details.

#### Weather: Change city name

You'll want to modify this section of code and change `Edmonton` to your city name:

```bash
# Replace Edmonton with your city name, GPS, etc. See: curl wttr.in/:help
curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0 --silent --max-time 3
# Timeout #. Increase for slow connection---^
```

Unicode is supported for city names like `/Москва` (Moscow). Airport letters are supported such as `YEG` for Edmonton.

#### Weather: Remove country name

When terminal is set for 92 characters wide, the weather displays as "Edmonton, Canada." which is too long for my liking:

[image: Weather with country.png]

Worse yet when terminal is set for default 80 characters wide:

[image: Weather country name 80 chars.png]

To circumvent the problem, ", Countryname" is blanked out on the screen with this code:

```bash
# Depending on length of your city name and country name you will:
#   1. Comment out next three lines of code. Uncomment fourth code line.
#   2. Change subtraction value and set number of print spaces to match
#      subtraction value. Then place comment on fourth code line.
Column=$(($DateColumn - 10))
tput cuf $Column        # Move x column number
printf "          "     # Blank out ", country" with x spaces
#tput cuf $DateColumn    # Position to column 27 for date display
```

If you need help with this part of the script please post comment below for assistance.

### Terminal screen width adjustments

Adjust the spacing to your terminal screen width by changing:

```bash
# Setup for 92 character wide terminal
DateColumn=34 # Default is 27 for 80 character line, 34 for 92 character line
TimeColumn=61 # Default is 49 for   "   "   "   "    61 "   "   "   "
```

---

## Tying it all together in `~/.bashrc`

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add these lines to the bottom:

```bash
# Splash Calendar and time
now

# ASCII Linux distribution display
screenfetch
```

Save the `~/.bashrc" file changes.

To display the Ubuntu information you need `screenfetch`:

```bash
sudo apt install screenfetch
```

There are similar display packages to `screenfetch` so shop around!

If you want the same command prompt with "─────────" dividing line between commands, change these lines:

```bash
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Note the length of the separator line coincides with width of `screenfetch` output. In this case it is 92 characters wide and `gnome-terminal` preferences are set accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure the ssh daemon to display a message during login. Specify the file to display with the Banner directive in the sshd_config file:

```
Banner /etc/ssh/ssh_banner
```

The filename can be any file, but for sanity I keep it in /etc/ssh along with the sshd_config file.

Answer (score 0):

One little script to generate the /etc/issue with network address in /etc/rc.local of debian host.

```
/bin/echo "This is \n(\s \m \r) \t \l">/etc/issue
/bin/sleep 10 # This is optional, sometimes OS need more time to get ip address while DHCP, otherwise maybe you will get nothing :(
/sbin/ip a| /bin/grep inet| /bin/grep -v -E "inet6|127.0.0.1"| /bin/sed "s/\s*//"|/bin/sed "s/\/24.*//" >>/etc/issue
```

update: 
sounds it's enough with "ip -4 -br a"
thanks @Mathieu CAROFF !

Comment: `man ip`. Use the `-br` switch. You might also want to use the `-4` switch. Your command can be shortened to `ip -br a | sed -nE 's:^(\w+)\s+UP\s+([0-9.]+)/.*$:\1 \2:p'`. Even better, use `hostname -I`.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT for use this ssh Banner:
Day Highlighting only works with "ncal -bh > /tmp/terminal" instead of cal -h. 
cal -h doesnt work/exist anymore (Ubuntu 18.04)